# Micronaut data with Reactive mongodb + JPA/Hibernate Repository

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to use reactive MongoDb with JPA (RxJavaCrudRepository. Is there any sample reference so that I can follow.

```
implementation("io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive")
```

I found this one https://github.com/ilopmar/micronaut-mongo-reactive-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/mongoreactive/MongoController.java but this sample is using MongoClient.

Is there any post or sample example it will be great

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It seems it's not possible to use JPA with Mongo.

Comment: As per the github project https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/projects/5 they have planned, but not yet implemeted